# What is the type of the object which is assigned to null

Tags: scala

In following code, what is the type of `s`

```
scala> val s:String = null
s: String = null

//cannot check if instance is of type Null
scala> s.isInstanceOf[Null]
<console>:13: error: type Null cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceOf test
       s.isInstanceOf[Null]
                     ^

//s is no longer a String or Any or AnyRef
scala> s.isInstanceOf[String]
res2: Boolean = false 

scala> s.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]
res4: Boolean = false

scala> s.isInstanceOf[Any]
res5: Boolean = false

scala> s.isInstanceOf[Object]
res11: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the null is just null and it will not be as object,where the object is father of all classes then if null is an object then this code should return true

`val s:String=null;println(s.isInstanceOf[Object])`

but actually it returns false so the null is just null and it will not have any type :D see the snapshot [image]

Comment: "null is just null and it will not have any type" – That is not true. The type of `null` is `scala.Null`. `scala.Null` is the *Bottom Type* for reference types, so it is a subtype of *every* subtype of `scala.AnyRef` (including `scala.AnyRef`) itself. So, the statement that "`null` will not have any type" is wrong. In fact, `null` has not just any type, but *all types* (or at least all reference types).

Comment: Well, then if we do it like isInstanceof[scala.null] will it be true ?